# Assigning values to a position in a numpy array not modifying the array

Tags: python, arrays, python-3.x, numpy, type-coercion

how to get exact value when I use array? why the result is array([0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]) but not 0.7?

```
overlap= np.array([0]*10)
tempi = np.zeros(10)
for i in range(10):
    for j in range(10):
        tempi[j] = 0.7;
    overlap[i] = max(tempi)
    print(max(tempi))

overlap
```

Answer (score 3):

`overlap` was (implicitly) declared as an integer array. As you assign floats to positions in integer arrays, they're truncated (implicitly coerced to integers).

What you'd want to do, is declare `overlap` to have a `dtype` of `float` -

```
overlap = np.array([0] * 10, dtype=np.float)
```

Or,

```
overlap = np.array([0.] * 10)
```

Running this again, you get what you expect.